# Group Module - have access only to content created by group members

Tags: users

I am using [Group Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) and I have many groups and each member is creating new nodes every day.

What I need:
Only the members from a specific group can view/edit the nodes created by the members of the exact same group. **I want a full closed circle.**

Let me refrain with this:

Group 1 has users:

1. Moderador - Can see its own content and all the content created by member 2 and 3. Can't see content created by user 4,5,6 because they are in a different group.
2. Member - Can see content created by him alone, not others.
3. Member - Can see content created by him alone, not others.

Group 2 has users:

4. Moderador - Can see its own content and all the content created by member 2 and 3. Can't see content created by user 1,2,3 because they are in a different group.
5. Member - Can see content created by him alone, not others.
6. Member - Can see content created by him alone, not others.

I searched in the permissions but I can't figure this out.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: I know a bit about the Group module, but I do not understand your question. Want to retry? Questions I ask myself about this question: What do you mean by that "full closed circle"? What are you missing in the various (extra) permissions provide by the Group module? Maybe you want to make something happen automatically? "They can see each others member profiles": is that what you want or do not want at all?

Comment: I only noticed now you improved your question from before (since you did not include my username in your comment, I got no notify). extra questions: (a) for bullet 4, I think "member 2 and 3" should be replaced by "member 5 and 6", right? (b) for bullet 2, the "not others", do you mean "nobody from Group 2, and also not from anybody else from Group 1" (and similar for bullet 3, 5 and 6)? (c) Do group 1 and group 2 have the SAME group ***type***, or would it be OK to have a separate group type for each group?